# How to Print DataGridView Data using CrystalReports in VB.NET and MS ACCESS

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports

I'm wondering how can I print my Data in DataGridView using CrystalReports.

My DataGridView is already connected to my MS ACCESS DATABASE. And I already finished the sorting and searching functions. However, my problem is how can I print my data from DataGridView after searching/sorting using CrystalReports.
Can someone help with this? Thank You so much.

I don't have any code yet because I don't know where to start the process.

Comment: Hmm, kind of kludgy but maybe save report in CR with a specific sproc name. Then overwrite the query/stored procedure with the query behind your DGV? The columns would have to be the same to match the definition in CR... Seems like an XY problem here to be honest.

Comment: what could be the best possible way on printing my data using crystalreports?

Comment: I googled "print DatGridView in Crystal Reports" and got 70 thousand hits. Maybe one of those could get you started. Then you could post if you have a specific programming problem.